# Microsoft word CV is repeating the third row of text when printing or pdf output

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, formatting

I'm trying to print my CV for an event, I hardly ever need hardcopies of course but now that I do, I've discovered that the first page of the document is doing this;

[Word table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc1gc.png)

This is laid out in a basic table. The date and employer information is one column, the job description text is the second column. Each job takes up one row. On this first page, when printing or saving as PDF, the text in the second column of the third row is being overlaid on top of the first and second rows. I've never seen this before in my life and can't figure out what's causing it! It's only happening on page 1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Microsoft Word is weird with tables, but even I've never seen anything like this. As with other triaging techniques, have you tried removing large chunks of the document, to narrow down the particular table area or line of text that might be contributing to the problem? *(make sure to save copies of the original file first)*